# printing DEBUG log in console, how to disable it

Tags: java

getting many debug printing in cosole how to disable it?
00:00:39.293 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4j2LoggerProvider

tryed to write in app.properties `logging.level.root=info`
and `-Dlogging.level.org.springframework=INFO` in run/debug configuration->program arguments

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="connection.password">user</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>


        <mapping class="dmdev.lesson.entity.User"/>

        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using JBoss; it uses Log4J as its logger.

You will need to configure JBoss/Log4J to change the log level. That can be done through JBoss's CLI, Admin Page, or by modifying `standalone.xml`.

This links should help:

- [JBoss AS 7.2 - Logging Configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Logging%20Configuration.html)
- [Configure Root Logger](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/logging_with_jboss_eap#configure_root_logger)
- [Another SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61830114/4468380)